# How to postpone a function call until a module is imported?

Tags: python, module, python-import

Is it possible to postpone running functionality until a module is imported?

For example, say I have this expression:

```
import multiprocessing.spawn
python_exe = search_env_for_python() # this might be slow.
multiprocessing.spawn.set_executable(python_exe)
```

I would like to postpone calling `search_env_for_python` until the multiprocessing module is imported.

Is there a way to delay the function call until the module is imported?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the sys module.

```
import sys

modulename = 'multiprocessing.spawn'
  if modulename in sys.modules:
     python_exe = search_env_for_python()
```

Comment: This only runs the operation when the module is imported, it doesn't delay the operation until the module is imported.

Comment: `while modulename not in sys.modules: `?

Comment: That prevents execution from continuing.